# Display the text of a checkable combobox to a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qcombobox

My code has a combobox with checkboxes and everytime I check a checkbox I want to display the text in a QTableWidget row and if a checkbox is unchecked I want to delete the row from the QTableWidget.

Comment: Why a QTableWidget? How many columns does the QTableWidget have? If you just want to show a text, I think a QListView or QListWidget would be enough

Comment: I need to display the text from checked checkbox along with some count. Hence the QTableWidget should have a minimum of 2 columns and the rows should increase or decrease as and when you select/de-select the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although initially managing the logic with a QTableWidget with a QCombobox seems simple in the long term it could be complicated. A more elegant solution is to use a model that will be shared by the QComboBox and QTableView where the filtering is done by a QSortFilterProxyModel, when sharing both elements the same model will see the checkbox in the QTableWidget which is removed with a delegate.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CheckedFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        index = self.sourceModel().index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        return index.data(QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole) == QtCore.Qt.Checked


class RemoveCheckBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(RemoveCheckBoxDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.features &= ~QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasCheckIndicator


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.m_tableview = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
        self.m_proxy = CheckedFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.m_proxy.setSourceModel(self.m_model)

        self.m_combobox.setModel(self.m_model)
        self.m_tableview.setModel(self.m_proxy)

        delegate = RemoveCheckBoxDelegate(self)
        self.m_tableview.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_combobox)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_tableview)

        options = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]

        self.fill_combobox(options)

    def fill_combobox(self, options):
        self.m_model.clear()
        for option in options:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(option)
            item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            item.setData(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked, QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole)
            items = [item] + [
                QtGui.QStandardItem() for _ in range(self.m_model.rowCount() - 1)
            ]
            self.m_model.appendRow(items)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. It works exactly as I wanted it to.
Can I do the following in this code?
**Question 1: If I have to limit the number of columns in the QTableView to 2, then what should I do?**
With the above code ,the number of columns in QTableView is one less than length of the list 'options'. I do not need the additional columns.

**Question 2: How to rename the column headers to some strings instead of the numbers 1, 2?**